# Having trouble with nesting while loops in C program

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, nest

I am working on a query program to search for specific vehicle model from a CSV file. The format of CSV file is as follows:

```
2000,VOLVO,V70 T5 TURBO,STATION WAGON,2.3,A4,Z,12.4,8.0,2084,4793
2000,VOLVO,V70R AWD TURBO,STATION WAGON,2.4,A5,Z,13.1,9.2,2269,5219
2001,ACURA,3.2TL,MID-SIZE,3.2,AS5,Z,12.3,7.4,2019,4644
2001,ACURA,INTEGRA,SUBCOMPACT,1.8,A4,X,10.0,7.1,1739,4000
...
2014,VOLVO,XC90 AWD,SUV - STANDARD,3.2,AS6,X,13.3,8.6,2240,258
```

The struct of CSV is CarRecord in the code below.

Each year has zero or one record that matches the query. So if I find record in 2000 matches, print out the data, and jump to 2001 to continue searching, if 2001 has no record that match the query, print out "2001 No record", can anyone help me figure out where do I insert "2001 No record" in my code?

```
struct CarRecord{
    int year;
    char make[20];
    char model[40];
    char type[30];
    float engineSize;
    char transmissionType[4];
    char fuelType;
    float city;
    float hwy;
    float fuelPerYear;
    float co2;
}data[14500];

struct QueryS{
    char make[20];
    char model[40];
    char transmissionType[4];
    float engineSize;
}squery[100];

int x=0;
int ctr=0;
int compareyear=2000;
while (compareyear==data[x].year){  //assume that there are no more than 14500 records.
    for(x=0;x<14500;x++){
        if (strcmp(squery[ctr].make,data[x].make) == 0 && strcmp(squery[ctr].model, data[x].model) == 0 && strcmp(squery[ctr].transmissionType, data[x].transmissionType) == 0 && squery[ctr].engineSize==data[x].engineSize){
            fprintf(otreport," %4d | %14.1f | %17.1f | %21.0f | %10.0f \n", data[x].year, data[x].city, data[x].hwy, data[x].fuelPerYear, data[x].co2);
            compareyear++;
            x++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (compareyear==compareyear==data[x].year)` seems to be a little _too_ interested in `compareyear`.

Comment: Use a `for` loop for the outer `while`, and use braces around the body of a loop when the statement is not a single line.  Your indentation is misleading; `x++;` is indented one level too many, and the second close brace after that doesn't match any open brace in the code shown.

Answer (score 2):

If `compareyear != data[x].year` then your code enters an infinite loop, since `x` is not incremented in the first loop. I would add `x++` to both loops.

Also, `compareyear == compareyear == data[x].year` is probably not what you want. `compareyear == compareyear` evaluates to `1`, so the entire expression only evaluates to `true` if `1 == data[x].year`. Rewrite the expression as `compareyear == data[x].year`

I'm also not entirely sure why you have a nested loop in the first place, there's no need for it in your code.

Comment: Thanks, could you help me figure out where do I insert "2001 No record" in my code?